# Flink kafka consumer fetch messages from specific partition

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

We want to achieve parallelism while reading a message form kafka. hence we wanted to specify partition number in flinkkafkaconsumer. It will read messages from all partition in kafka instead of specific partition number. Below is sample code:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");
properties.setProperty("group.id", "Message-Test-Consumers");
properties.setProperty("partition", "1"); //not sure about this syntax.

FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> kafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<String>("EventLog", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties);
```

Please suggest any better option to get the parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a mechanism to restrict which partitions Flink will read from. Nor do I see how this would help you achieve your goal of reading from the partitions in parallel, which Flink does regardless.

The Flink Kafka source connector reads from all available partitions, in parallel. Simply set the parallelism of the kafka source connector to whatever parallelism you desire, keeping in mind that the effective parallelism cannot exceed the number of partitions. In this way, each instance of Flink's Kafka source connector will read from one or more partitions. You can also configure the kafka consumer to automatically discover new partitions that may be created while the job is running.